# Why is $x^4+x^2+1$ over $_2$ a reducible polynomial? What do I misunderstand?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I don't quite understand when a polynomial is irreducible and when it's not.

Take $x^2 +1$ over $_3$.

As far as I know, I have to do the following:

0 1 2 using $x \in _3$

1 2 2 using $p(x)$

I calculated it like that:

$(0^2 + 1) \mod 3 = 1$

$(1^2 + 1) \mod 3 = 2$

$(2^2 + 1) \mod 3 = 1$

This is **irreducible** because in none of them the result is $0$.

Now take $x^2 + 1$ over $_2$

The same approach:

0 1 using $x \in _2$

1 2 using $p(x)$

$(0^2 + 1) \mod 2 = 1$

$(1^2 + 1) \mod 2 = 0$

This is **reducible** because the result is $0$ in the latter case.

Now take $x^4+x^2+1$ over $_2$.

0 1 using $x \in _2$

1 1 using $p(x)$

$(0^4+0^2 + 1) \mod 2 = 1 $

$(1^4+1^2 + 1) \mod 2 = 1 $

Why is this polynomial still reducible even though we get both times $1$ as a result?

Can someone clarify?

Comment: You are only looking for roots. This is not enough.

Comment: In $\mathbb F_2$ you have $x^n\equiv x$ this is why you are left with just $1$ (since $x^4+x^2=x+x=0$). Any polynomial will reduce to degree $1$ ultimately.

Comment: because $(x^2+x+1)^2\equiv x^4+x^2+1 $ over $\mathbb F_2$

Comment: It's because $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+x+1)^2$ over $\Bbb F_2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, just like in almost all fields, it is possible that a polynomial of degree $4$ is the product of two polynomials of degree $2$, neither of which happens to have a root.

Comment: I don't understand. So my approach only works for polynomials with a degree $<= 3$?

Comment: Correct. Your approach only works for polynomials of degree $2$ or $3.$ @JavaTeachMe2018

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So what needs to be done if it's $_5$ or higher?

Comment: It’s not a question of the field size, but the degree of the polynomial. @JavaTeachMe2018

Comment: Does that mean any polynomical of degree $>= 4$ is irreducible?

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 Not necessarily. In $\Bbb R[x]$ every polynomial of degree $\ge3$ is reducible, whereas $\Bbb F_{p^n}[x]$ and $\Bbb Q[x]$ have irreducible polynomials of all degrees.

Comment: @Gae.S. Can you give me an example to clarify please

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 An example of what? Like, that in $\Bbb R[x]$ we have $x^4+1=(x^2+\sqrt2x+1)(x^2-\sqrt2x+1)$ ?

Comment: @Gae.S. Take $x^3+x+1$. It's irreducible over $_5$ and $_6$. Is there any $F_{p^n}[x]$ where it is reducible?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the field $\Bbb F_6$". $x^3+x+1$ is completely factorisable in $\Bbb F_{125}[x]$, for instance.

Comment: @Gae.S. My bad. How did you figure out $_{125}[x]$ so fast? What is the approach you use?

Comment: $125=5^3{}{}{}$

Comment: It is a fact that, in any given algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_p$, there is exactly one subfield of cardinality $p^n$. Since for any two roots $\alpha,\beta\in\overline{\Bbb F}_p$ of an irreducible polynomial $g\in \Bbb F_p[x]$ we have that $\Bbb F_p[\alpha]\cong\Bbb F_p[\beta]\cong\Bbb F_{p^{\deg g}}$, it follows that the two extensions must coincide, and therefore that an irreducible polynomial $g$ splits in $\Bbb F_{p^{\deg g}}$.